# Changing list values

Tags: python, list

I want to change values in a list in my dict with multiple keys for my user ranks to something else without changing the order and not using using `.append` or `.remove`. The list contains the rank, rank title, set by, and `time.time()`. For example:

```
 [1, "user", "joseph", 12324544]
```

I want to change that to:

```
[4, "staff", "charles", time.time()]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: What?! Where is the rest of the data structure? Where are the new values coming from? Could you just replace the whole list with a new one? Where is your code so far?

Comment: Sorry xD I'm not 100% sure on how to replace the whole list with a new one yet.

Comment: And the set I'm using  is {"charles": {"rank": [5, "owner", "bot", time.time()], "points": 1, "claims": list(), "owned": False, "alert": False, "notes": list()}

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to a slice:

```
>>> import time
>>> l =  [1, "user", "joseph", 12324544]
>>> id(l)
140172281932256
>>> l[:] = [4, "staff", "charles", time.time()]
>>> id(l)
140172281932256
```

Alternatively (instead of `l[:] = [4, "staff", "charles", time.time()]`), use simple assignment, as in

```
l[0] = 4
l[1] = "staff"
l[2] = "charles"
l[3] = time.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable. Either reassign it whole-cloth or change each element individually using indexing.

```
lst = [1, 'user', "joseph", 12324544]

lst = [4, "staff", "charles", time.time()] # ta-da

# alternatively
lst[0] = 4
lst[1] = "staff"
lst[2] = "charles"
lst[3] = time.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT after your recent comment:

You have:

```
d = {"charles": {"rank": [1, "user", "bot", 1399505479.158], "points": 1, "claims": list(), "owned": False, "alert": False, "notes": list()}}
```

To change the rank of the user "charles":

```
d['charles']['rank'] = [5, 'owner', 'bot', time.time()]
```

or, to change one of the values in that list:

```
d['charles']['rank'][0] = 5
d['charles']['rank'][1] = 'owner'
d['charles']['rank'][2] = 'bot'
d['charles']['rank'][3] = time.time()
```

#### Original answer:

From my understanding, you have a dict with multiple keys, say:

```
d = {'Key1': [1, 'user', 'joseph', 12324544], 'Key2': [2, 'user', 'jim', 12324545]}
```

To change the values in the list of the first key ("Key1"), you could do

```
d['Key1'][0] = 4
d['Key1'][1] = 'staff'
d['Key1'][2] = 'charles'
d['Key1'][3] = time.time()
```

which would result in

```
[4, 'staff', 'charles', 1399505116.365]
```

for

```
d['Key1']
```

without using .append or .remove

Comment: Couldn't I do  d[key1] = [4, "staff", "charles", time.time()]?